# Ubuntu KDE unlock screen

Tags: 20.04, kde, lock-screen

I have an issue with the unlock screen in KDE.

When I lock my screen, then try to unlock it. I have no prompt to type my password. Nothing. Just a blank screen with the background image.

I have to open another session (terminal), then unlock the screen manually (search for the GUI session, then unlock it) :

```
loginctl list-session

loginctl unlock-session
```

Any advice please ?

---

Release:        20.04

Comment: Don't know. What happens if you (temporarily) set it to unlock without a password?

Comment: How to do it ? I can't find any option to unlock it without password.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the recent **Ubuntu updates**, or the fact that **I changed the theme for the login / password screen**. But now it is working.